# Dynamically update some part of text in SQL Server column content

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have tried this script to update by removing some part of text in the description field in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE products
SET description = LEFT(description, CHARINDEX('<b>Please select xxxx</b>', description) - 1)
WHERE productid = 'abc'
```

It works fine, but I am unable to update it dynamically to the all the products.

Comment: please make it clear: what do you mean by dynamic? replace different text for different product?

Comment: Exactly i have to replace different text for different products.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE products
SET    description = Replace(description, '<b>Please select xxxx</b>', '')
WHERE  description LIKE '%<b>Please select xxxx</b>%';
```

Answer (score 0):

probably use case-when condition:

```
UPDATE  products
SET     Description = REPLACE(Description,
                       CASE WHEN ProductId = 1 THEN 'Your pattern for product 1'
                            WHEN ProductId = 2 THEN 'Your Pattern for Product 2'
                            -- WHEN ProductId = 3 THEN ...
                            ELSE '' -- Default empty
                       END, '');
```

--- only if you are sure there are not too many products :)

Comment: I need to apply this for thousands of products

Comment: then there must be a specific pattern for each product, isn't it? otherwise you have to write one update statement for each product that to be updated